# Strange jQuery dialog behaivor in Chrome. Working in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dialog

I hava a dialog but it is not working properly in Chrome but it does in IE.

I am working in this beta page:

**http://www.parlamentoabierto.mx/** 
**You can see the malfunction if you go to the map and click on it.**
The modal background is not fully disappearing.

```
  dialog = $("#modal-mapa");
  console.log(dialog);
    dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 700,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
  dialogClass: 'ventanaModal',
    open: function(event, ui) { console.log(dialog.dialog('option','position')); $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () { $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); }); }
    });
```

My guess can be that the version of the jQuery is not the best but that wont be easy to correct.

Comment: I get the same results in IE and Chrome.  No console error is logged.  Do you see an error message somewhere?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I see no console errors in Chrome, either.

Comment: When you click on the map.
Can you confirm this?